# How to solve Chinese Whispers Python Issue 'AttributeError: 'Graph' object has no attribute 'node'

Tags: python, algorithm, graph, networkx

I am trying to implement the Chinese Whispers Algorithm, but I can not figure out the issue below: the result that I want to get is like in the picture below

```py
import networkx as nx
from random import shuffle as shuffle
# build nodes and edge lists
nodes = [
    (1,{'attr1':1}),
    (2,{'attr1':1})

]
edges = [
    (1,2,{'weight': 0.732})

]
# initialize the graph
G = nx.Graph()
# Add nodes
G.add_nodes_from(nodes)
# CW needs an arbitrary, unique class for each node before initialisation
# Here I use the ID of the node since I know it's unique
# You could use a random number or a counter or anything really
for n, v in enumerate(nodes):
  G.node[v[0]]["class"] = v[1]["attr1"]
# add edges
G.add_edges_from(edges)
# run Chinese Whispers
# I default to 10 iterations. This number is usually low.
# After a certain number (individual to the data set) no further clustering occurs
iterations = 10
for z in range(0,iterations):
    gn = G.nodes()
    # I randomize the nodes to give me an arbitrary start point
    shuffle(gn)
    for node in gn:
        neighs = G[node]
        classes = {}
        # do an inventory of the given nodes neighbours and edge weights
        for ne in neighs:
            if isinstance(ne, int) :
                if G.node[ne]['class'] in classes:
                    classes[G.node[ne]['class']] += G[node][ne]['weight']
                else:
                    classes[G.node[ne]['class']] = G[node][ne]['weight']
        # find the class with the highest edge weight sum
        max = 0
        maxclass = 0
        for c in classes:
            if classes[c] > max:
                max = classes[c]
                maxclass = c
        # set the class of target node to the winning local class
        G.node[node]['class'] = maxclass
```

I want to make this output
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tr2AO.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted in the answer by @Shridhar R Kulkarni, you want to use `G.nodes` when referencing nodes for updating/adding attributes.

Another problem with the script is that for shuffling, you want only the list of node identifiers:

```py
    gn = list(G.nodes()) # use list() to allow shuffling
    shuffle(gn)
```

If you are interested in just the computation, rather than (re)implementation, you could also use an existing library [`chinese-whispers`](https://pypi.org/project/chinese-whispers/).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Also, I want to make the change in the nodes with squares so the text in the output is inside the square like in the picture. Thank you, I appreciate your help :) I want to make this output
[enter image description here][1]



  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tr2AO.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Use `G.nodes` instead of `G.node`.

Comment: I tried now I have this problem

Comment: I tried but it shows me the error below: 
 gn = G.nodes()
  TypeError: 'NodeView' object does not support item assignment

Comment: Hey, I see that you are new to this community. The community is always ready to help you. Though, it is recommended to do some prior research. You can search the error on stack overflow or on the internet. Now that your original error has been solved, you should create a separate post if you have another doubt instead of changing the same post or adding more problems in the same post. Also, read https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/30852374)

Comment: @jcoppens: Why do you think this is a new question? It looks like an answer to me?